# Type mismatch, “char” does not match with “char[]” in Processing

Tags: processing

I am trying to run this Processing code taken from [this website](https://community.dfrobot.com/makelog-308499.html) to create a wavelength meter.

```
/***************************************************************************
Created by dbc0301
***************************************************************************/
 
import processing.serial.*;
Serial port;
 
PFont myFont;
 
int tmp;
//int begin='$';//begin
int end='\r';//end
char rev[] = new char[15];//datas
int revFlag=0;
 
int[] data=new int[10];//F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,Clear,NIR
//int F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,Clear,NIR;
 
//Stimulus Function
float[] Fx={0.07763, 0.34806, 0.09564, 0.02910, 0.51205, 1.02630, 0.64240, 0.04677};
float[] Fy={0.00218, 0.02980, 0.13902, 0.60820, 1.00000, 0.75700, 0.26500, 0.01700};
float[] Fz={0.37130, 1.78260, 0.81295, 0.11170, 0.00575, 0.00110, 0.00005, 0.00000};
 
int textHight=25;
float rt=1;//Length scaling
 
void receiveDatas(){
    for(int i=0;port.available()>0;i++){
      tmp=port.read();
      if(tmp!=end){
        rev=char(tmp);
      }else{
        rev=char(tmp);
        revFlag=1;
        tmp=port.read();
        break;
      }
    }
}
 
void setup(){
  //size(1074,241);
  size(1250,301);
  background(0);//white255 black0
  noStroke();
  myFont = createFont("Microsoft YaHei", 20);
  textFont(myFont);
 
  println(Serial.list()[0]);
  port = new Serial(this,Serial.list()[0],115200);
}
 
void draw(){
  receiveDatas();
  if(revFlag==1){
    String[] m=match(new String(rev), "(.*?):(.*?)\r");//Regular Expression Matching 
    //printArray(m);
    try{
      if(m[1].equals("F1")){
        data[0]=int(m[2]);
      }else if(m[1].equals("F2")){
        data[1]=int(m[2]);
      }else if(m[1].equals("F3")){
        data[2]=int(m[2]);
      }else if(m[1].equals("F4")){
        data[3]=int(m[2]);
      }else if(m[1].equals("F5")){
        data[4]=int(m[2]);
      }else if(m[1].equals("F6")){
        data[5]=int(m[2]);
      }else if(m[1].equals("F7")){
        data[6]=int(m[2]);
      }else if(m[1].equals("F8")){
        data[7]=int(m[2]);
      }else if(m[1].equals("Clear")){
        data[8]=int(m[2]);
      }else if(m[1].equals("NIR")){
        data[9]=int(m[2]);
      }else{
        print("Wrong datas!");
      }
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
      println(rev);
      printArray(m);
    }finally{}
    revFlag=0;
    //printArray(data);
    //delay(10);
  }
 
  /*Display*/
  //rectMode(CORNER);
  background(0);
  textSize(20);
 
  fill(#8b3dc5);
  rect(0,0,data[0]*rt,30);//F1
  text(data[0], data[0]*rt, 0+textHight);//textHeight: veritcal height of text
 
  fill(#00528e);
  rect(0,30,data[1]*rt,30);//F2
  text(data[1], data[1]*rt, 30+textHight);
 
  fill(#00b1ed);
  rect(0,60,data[2]*rt,30);//F3
  text(data[2], data[2]*rt, 60+textHight);
 
  fill(#01ffcd);
  rect(0,90,data[3]*rt,30);//F4
  text(data[3], data[3]*rt, 90+textHight);
 
  fill(#00af50);
  rect(0,120,data[4]*rt,30);//F5
  text(data[4], data[4]*rt, 120+textHight);
 
  fill(#ffff01);
  rect(0,150,data[5]*rt,30);//F6
  text(data[5], data[5]*rt, 150+textHight);
 
  fill(#ffc000);
  rect(0,180,data[6]*rt,30);//F7
  text(data[6], data[6]*rt, 180+textHight);
 
  fill(#c10005);
  rect(0,210,data[7]*rt,30);//F8
  text(data[7], data[7]*rt, 210+textHight);
 
  fill(#ffffff);
  rect(0,240,data[8]*rt,30);//Clear
  text(data[8], data[8]*rt, 240+textHight);
 
  fill(#888888);
  rect(0,270,data[9]*rt,30);//F8
  text(data[9], data[9]*rt, 270+textHight);
 
  //delay(1);
 
  /*Color Temperaure*/
  float X,Y,Z,x,y,n,temp;
  X=(data[0]*Fx[0] + data[1]*Fx[1] + data[2]*Fx[2] + data[3]*Fx[3] + data[4]*Fx[4] + data[5]*Fx[5] + data[6]*Fx[6] + data[7]*Fx[7]);//20/1000;//20 is the interval of integration. 1000 is used to converted the value into a real number between 0~1 
  Y=(data[0]*Fy[0] + data[1]*Fy[1] + data[2]*Fy[2] + data[3]*Fy[3] + data[4]*Fy[4] + data[5]*Fy[5] + data[6]*Fy[6] + data[7]*Fy[7]);//20/1000;//But it is meaningless to multiply this number here since it will be reduced in the next step
  Z=(data[0]*Fz[0] + data[1]*Fz[1] + data[2]*Fz[2] + data[3]*Fz[3] + data[4]*Fz[4] + data[5]*Fz[5] + data[6]*Fz[6] + data[7]*Fz[7]);//20/1000;
 
  x=X/(X+Y+Z);
  y=Y/(X+Y+Z);
 
  n=(x-0.3320)/(0.1858-y);
  temp=437*n*n*n+3601*n*n+6831*n+5517;
  print(temp);
  println("K\n");
 
}
```

It is giving me this error on line 24 and 26:

> Type mismatch, “char” does not match with “char[]”

Comment: That's because `rev` is a `char[]` (meaning, a `char` array), but you assign a single `char` to it.

Comment: I'm confused. This isn't valid arduino (C++) code. It more looks like java, but Java doesn't run on Arduinos.

Comment: rev=char(tmp); -> what does char(tmp) return? if it's a char, you'll need to point to an index of rev to assign the value, like: rev[0]=char(tmp);,

Comment: @PMF It's Processing code _talking_ to an Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `rev` is an array. If you want to put `tmp` in rev, do something like `rev[0] = char(tmp)`. I don't understand well your code, but if you want every letter you press to be added to `tmp`, you could make a variable to take count of how much letters were pressed, and do `rev[typed] = char(tmp)` where `typed` is the variable in question. Also, this code will probably confuse most of the community, go to [discourse.processing.org](https://discourse.processing.org) to ask Processing questions. Hope i could help, though!